# Querying contour lines for elevation at point using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Is there a way to interpolate between these contour lines for a given point using postgis?

I've come up with the following query to gather the potential contour lines of interest:

```
        $sql = "SELECT
                    osm_id,
                    ele,
                    ST_AsGeoJSON(way) AS geojson,
                    ST_distance(way, ST_Transform(GeomFromText('POINT(".$lon." ".$lat.")',4326),900913)) AS dist,
                    ST_ClosestPoint(way,ST_Transform(GeomFromText('POINT(".$lon." ".$lat.")',4326),900913)) as closest,
                    ST_Azimuth(ST_Transform(GeomFromText('POINT(".$lon." ".$lat.")',4326),900913), ST_ClosestPoint(way,ST_Transform(GeomFromText('POINT(".$lon." ".$lat.")',4326),900913)))/(2*pi())*360 as angle
                FROM
                    planet_osm_line
                WHERE
                    way && ST_Transform(GeomFromText('POINT(".$lon." ".$lat.")',4326),900913)
                ORDER BY
                    dist
                LIMIT 10";
```

The post processing of these results I will just describe rather than posting my convoluted code.  It seems the real crux of the problem is finding the two contours of interest.  Using the two closest contours isn't always the best or even accurate solution as they may both be on one side of the point of interest.

What I did was accept the closest contour as a keeper. Then check the azimuth between the point of interest and the closest point and compare this azimuth to the similiar azimuth calculated from the first accepted contour.  The closer the delta between these two was to 180 the higher the probability that this was my second contour.

Comment: What contour lines?

Comment: the contour lines in my contours db, which are line geometries.  I don't need the whole query to be spelled out for me, just a suggestion of which postgis function would get me there.

Comment: Answer posted with suggestions for functions to use -- hope this helps.

Comment: I am interested in a start-to-finish solution which is able to return the interpolated z value for any given pair of x and y, using a set of contours defined as three columns of the x, y, z values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [ST_Line_Interpolate_Point](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html) will interpolate the x, y and z values, given a line as input and a fraction along the line to interpolate to, eg,

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(0,0,0),
          ST_MakePoint(10, 10, 2)),.5));
```

returns `POINT Z (5 5 1)` as you would expect.

To create the line, you can use [ST_ClosestPoint](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html), which will return the nearest point on a line, to the point you are trying to interpolate to. If you do this for the nearest two contours, you can substitute the values into ST_MakeLine in place of the two ST_MakePoints above.

You may also find [ST_Line_Locate_Point](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_Line_Locate_Point.html) useful, for finding points on a line. You said you wanted pointers, rather than a full query, so I hope this helps.
`

Comment: Thank you John.  That was just enough to get me started. I'll post what I've come up with as an edit to my original question.

Comment: Interesting approach. I like your use of azimuth.